# If statement is unexpectedly running. How do I debug this?

Tags: java, while-loop

The purpose of this application is to get the full name of a user, and split them up. The results are printed.

`if(nameParts.length < 2|| nameParts.length > 3)` is somehow gaining control from the loop after it runs a 2nd time or beyond. I would assume that `name` and `nameParts` should be getting values assigned to them once again. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String choice = "y";

            System.out.println("Welcome to the name parser.\n");

            while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

                System.out.print("Enter a name: ");

                String name = sc.nextLine();
                String[] nameParts = nameSeperate(name);

                if(nameParts.length < 2|| nameParts.length > 3) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your full name or your first and last name.");
                    continue;
                }
                else if(nameParts.length == 2) {
                    System.out.println("First Name: " + nameParts[0]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: " + nameParts[0]);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("First Name: " + nameParts[0]);
                    System.out.println("Middle Name: " + nameParts[1]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: " + nameParts[2]);
                }
                System.out.println("Would you like to enter another name? (y/n)");    
                choice = sc.next();
            }            
        }
```

Here is the output:

```
Welcome to the name parser.

Enter a name: Alfons Pineda
First Name: Alfons
Last Name: Pineda
Would you like to enter another name? (y/n)
y
Enter a name: Please enter your full name or your first and last name.
Enter a name: Alfons Pineda
First Name: Alfons
Last Name: Pineda
Would you like to enter another name? (y/n)
n
```

Comment: If you use `choice = sc.nextLine();` instead of `next()` does the problem go away? I suspect that `next()` grabs the character but leaves the newline in the buffer for the next call to `nextLine()` to grab before you even have a chance to enter anything.

Comment: I do not believe that this was a duplicate, because I had no idea this was the fault of the Scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but for your first scan you use `sc.nextLine()` and for the second one just `sc.next()`. Maybe using `sc.nextLine()` also for the second statement would help. It could be, that the `\n` was not read by `sc.next()`.

Therefore in the second loop only the newline would be read by the first scan.

Comment: Brilliant answer! It actually works, and I will accept this answer.